# How to build mainline kernel and make it show up on GRUB?

Tags: 10.04, kernel, compiling, build

After successfully compiling and building my [mainline Kernel (2.6.32.25)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.32.25.tar.bz2) under my Ubuntu 10.04 with [these headers](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.32.25-lucid/) I was wondering: how to make this kernel on startup, so I can choose which one to boot?

I have GRUB2 (grup-install -v says: 'GNU GRUB 0.97') installed.

I tried this:

```
sudo make install
```

And got:

```
luky@ubuntu1004:/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.25$ sudo make install
sh /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.25/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 2.6.32.25 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
  System.map "/boot"
```

Here's my /boot folder:

```
luky@ubuntu1004:/boot$ ls
abi-2.6.32-24-generic         System.map-2.6.32-24-generic
config-2.6.32-24-generic      System.map-2.6.32.25
config-2.6.32.25              vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-24-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic
initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic  vmlinuz-2.6.32.25
memtest86+.bin
```

I would *NOT* like to have to manually change GRUB's config files.

Comment: Upstream kernels do not have a "-" in their version number, that is for package versions. It would be more clear if you said "2.6.32.25".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after all what solved my problem was: **install the grub-pc package.** This will replace the default one shipped with Ubuntu 10.04.

I'm on a PC, so I guess that's fine.

Comment: Maybe grub-pc ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have grub2 installed because you are running 10.04, rather than grub legacy. You will need to update grub following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

It should be a simple: sudo update-grub

This should check for new kernels and make grub entries from which you should be able to boot.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if that was the solution, since I also edited my /etc/default/grub file... but now it's showing up.

Next problem: Kernel panic: unable to mount root fs

LOL!

Comment: Thats because of your /dev/sda4 (or something) is missing in initramfs /dev folder. Try sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

Answer (score 1):

The kernels from that location are meant to be installed, not built yourself. They already have everything needed in their packaging to appear in grub, etc.

To build a mainline kernel and still get a proper `.deb` package, see the instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

That will guide you through the build prerequisites, how to transfer the build-time configs, and generate the package. If you don't need to change configurations, see http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/ for pre-built mainline kernels.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I downloaded the sources from kernel.org: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.32.25.tar.bz2

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect that? It changes the answer significantly. :)

Comment: yeah, done. sorry for the confusion! =)

Answer (score 0):

To build and install kernel in ubuntu or any debian based system for that matter its best to use makepkg istead of the usual make, make modules_install ....

`makepkg --initrd linux-image linux-headers` warning: this might throw a permission error some times

This creates a couple of .deb files in the parent directory which can be installed like any other .deb file.Do not worry about grub,it will configure itself;if using burg you must run "sudo update-burg".This will also ensure that the initrd file is properly generated

Comment: this command doesnt work.