# Kernel panic: unable to mount root fs after building mainline kernel

Tags: 10.04, kernel, compiling, build

Similar problem as [reported](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10049087) by another user. While booting, the system can't find `/dev/sda1` and so a "kernel panic: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)" appears on screen.

I'm compiled & built kernel linux-2.6.32.25 on Ubuntu 10.04 running in VirtualBox virtual machine.

ps.: The update-initramfs, update-grub didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to re-build the kernel using [make-dpkg as mentioned](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) in the Ubuntu wiki.

```
sudo make-kpkg buildpackage --initrd kernel-image kernel-headers
```

I generated the kernel-image with:

```
sudo make bzImage
```

If I recall well, on a PC this will output vimlinuz to: `/usr/src/[your_linux_source_tree]/arch/x86/build`

The headers I used were downloaded from [kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

Finally I did the [update-initramfs, update-grub trick](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10049087).

Grub screen not showing up? [Here's the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10464/how-to-build-mainline-kernel-and-make-it-show-up-on-grub)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: Please state what this command does so other users know.